# how to assign pointer value of another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
void funcF(char *outBuffer)
{
        char * inBuffer;
        inBuffer = (char *) malloc(500);
        // add stuff to inBuffer
        strcpy(inBuffer, "blabla");

        outBuffer = inBuffer; //probably this is wrong 
}

int main()
{
    char * outBuffer;

    funcF(outBuffer);

    printf("%s", outBuffer); // i want to get "blabla" as output
    free(outBuffer);
}
```

My question how can i make `outBuffer` point to the same address as `inBuffer` so that i can access the data in `inBuffer` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code passes a pointer by value.  This means that `funcF` operates on a copy of the caller's pointer.  If you want to modify the caller's pointer, you need to either pass the address of that pointer (i.e. a pointer to a pointer):

```
void funcF(char **outBuffer)
{
    char * inBuffer = malloc(500);
    strcpy(inBuffer, "blabla");
    *outBuffer = inBuffer;
}

int main()
{
    char * outBuffer;
    funcF(&outBuffer);
    //    ^
```

or change `funcF` to return a pointer:

```
char* funcF()
{
    char* inBuffer = malloc(500);
    strcpy(inBuffer, "blabla");
    return inBuffer;
}

int main()
{
    char * outBuffer = funcF();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `char **`:

```
void funcF(char **outBuffer)
```

then assign like this:

```
*outBuffer = inBuffer;
```

and pass it in like so:

```
funcF(&outBuffer);
```

you can alternatively, have it return a `char *`.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is what you want, but:

> int main() {
>
> ```
> const unsigned int MAX_BUFF = 1024
>
> char outBuffer[MAX_BUFF];
>
> funcF(outBuffer);
>
> printf("%s", outBuffer); // i want to get "blabla" as output
>
> /* free(outBuffer); */
> ```
>
> }

will have problem with free(), but you get the idea.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The questioner is asking about getting a pointer back from a called function, but your answer is about *not* getting a pointer back from the called function.

Comment: Sure, I noticed that. In the way I suggest the (hidden) pointer is send to the  called function - opposite to what was asked.